# Instrucción INSERT en conflicto con la restricción de una de mis llaves foráneas, por qué?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
create table Departamento(
    nroDepto varchar(4) primary key not null,
    nombreDepto varchar(15) not null,
    ciudad varchar(20) not null,
    director varchar(12) not null
);

create table Empleados (
    nDIEmp varchar(12) primary key not null,
    nomEmp varchar(40) not null,
    sexEmp char(1) not null check(sexEmp IN('M','F')),
    fecNac date not null,
    fecIncorporacion date not null,
    salEmp float not null,
    comis float not null,
    codSuc varchar(15) not null,
    jefeID varchar(12),
    cargoE varchar(15) not null,
    nroDepto  varchar(4) not null,
    constraint fk_empl foreign key (jefeID) references Empleados,
    constraint fk_dpto foreign key (nroDepto) references Departamento
);

select * from Departamento
insert into Departamento values ('1000','GERENCIA','CALI','31.840.269'),
                                ('1500','PRODUCCION','CALI','16.211.383'),
                                ('2000','VENTAS','CALI','31.178.144'),
                                ('3000','INVESTIGACION','CALI','16.759.060'),
                                ('3500','MERCADEO','CALI','22.222.222'),
                                ('2100','VENTAS','POPAYAN','31.751.219'),
                                ('2200','VENTAS','BUGA','768.782'),
                                ('2300','VENTAS','CARTAGO','737.689'),
                                ('4000','MANTENIMIENTO','CALI','333.333.333'),
                                ('4100','MANTENIMIENTO','POPAYAN','888.888'),
                                ('4200','MANTENIMIENTO','BUGA','11.111.111'),
                                ('4300','MANTENIMIENTO','CARTAGO','444.444')

select * from empleados
insert into empleados values('31.840.269', 'María Rojas', 'F','1959-01-15','16-05-1990','0001',6250000,1500000, '41.840.269','Gerente', '1000')
```

> Instrucción INSERT en conflicto con la restricción FOREIGN KEY SAME
>   TABLE 'fk_empl'. El conflicto ha aparecido en la base de datos
>   'intedix', tabla 'dbo.Empleados', column 'nDIEmp'. Se terminó la
>   instrucción.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tu tabla empleados tiene una foreign key en la columna jefeID. Esto significa que el valor que introduzcas en esa columna tiene que coincidir con el campo nDIEmp de un elemento de la misma tabla. En tu ejemplo, estás intentando insertar un registro con el campo jefeID = '41.840.269', pero no tienes ningún empleado en la tabla con nDIEmp = '41.840.269', de ahí el error.